# Using sqlite with ARC Welder and Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, google-chrome-arc

I have a Xamarin app that uses a sqlite data store (using sqlite-net).  When I use an ARC Welder to launch the app on a Windows machine I get the error.

```
E/mono-rt (  204): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 
    System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so
E/mono-rt (  204): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
E/mono-rt (  204): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewString (string) <0x00093>
E/mono-rt (  204): at Java.Lang.Throwable..ctor (string) <0x0003b>
E/mono-rt (  204): at Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable..ctor (System.Exception) <0x0001f>
E/mono-rt (  204): at Java.Lang.Throwable.FromException (System.Exception) <0x0009f>
E/mono-rt (  204): at Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledException (System.Exception) <0x0015f>
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem?  Is it possible to create a Android Java app that uses sqlite natively that runs on ARC Welder or is sqlite something not available to ARC?

Comment: none of my Xamarin based apps are running on arc welder but pure java with sqlite apps are running fine.

Answer (score 2):

If ARC does not create a /system/lib folder, here is an answer to a similar problem that may solve this. When the app starts, add the part to your own sqlite.so to the start of the PATH environment variable. (Found at:  https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/343)

```
string path=Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "lib");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path+";"+Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Sqlite for Android: https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Answer (score 1):

ARC does not create a /system/lib directory. The Android Framework *does* use SQLite internally, but for performance reasons we use a static library.

It seems reasonable for applications to want to load a shared library for their own use however. Please file a [bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG).

If you really need it now, you can probably include libsqlite.so in your .APK for ARC. However I'm not sure what you would have to do to sqlite-net to get it to load the .so from an alternate location.